# alpha channel in ggplot2 does not work after installing 2.15

Tags: r, ggplot2

after updating to R 2.15, the alpha channel in ggplot does not seem to work anymore.

```
plot(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),bg="#cc000055",pch=21)
```

works perfectly fine but

```
qplot(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),color="#cc000044")
```

does not! Also, the alpha() function from the ggplot2 package is not found anymore (I also tried ggplot2::alpha().

Is that a known problem? I wasn't able to find anything about online...

Thanks!

Comment: try `?alpha` to get more details about how to use it. This is working fine for me: `qplot(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),color="#cc000044", alpha=1/3)` Perhaps you need to update your ggplot2 library?

Comment: `qplot(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),color="#cc000044", alpha=1/3)` works for me too but `"#cc000044"` used to work before the update too. Also, the alpha function produces an error `Error: could not find function "alpha"` after calling `alpha(c("blue", "red"), .3)`, which is also in the `?alpha` help (last example on the bottom).

Comment: and I am using ggplot2 0.9, which I believe is the most recent version.

Comment: I now see that the alpha function has moved to the scales package. So after `library(scales)` `alpha(c("blue", "red"), .3)` works but `qplot(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),color="#cc000044")` still doesn't.

Comment: You need to wrap your colour spec in an `I()` otherwise it treats it as a factor level and uses the first colour of the default palette. It still doesn't fix the alpha issue though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can replicate the issue using R-2.15.0 and ggplot2 0.9.0.

As Ben noted, the standard way of specifying translucency in ggplot2 is to provide an explicit `alpha` argument.  You should try to use this for all new plotting code.

I think a case could made that ggplot should support legacy specification of alpha via the colour argument.  If you feel strongly about this, then [file an issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues).

Comment: Thanks! I will file an issue and also just posted on the google list [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ggplot2/8c-ofEvAyN4/DZOKwq7plZIJ). It not only the legacy specification but it's also standard R syntax for colors, which I think is a pretty good reason to support it...

Answer (score 2):

This is referenced in the comments above, but if you are working with some old ggplot code and R throws an error after a call to `alpha()` you need to explicitly load `library(scales)` into your R environment.