# Non-functioning ggplot alphas

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a semi-transparent rectangle the same colour as the background above a density curve so it creates a lighter-toned vertical area of the latter (a hack to visualise a range of interest such as rush hours).  As you can see the alpha fails. I wonder if anyone can get the following code working?

I'm aware there are other posts on ggplot's alpha channel issues ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053399/alpha-channel-in-ggplot2-does-not-work-after-installing-2-15)) but none seem to resolve this, and its not clear what the current situation is version-wise.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

```
d <- data.frame(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 100)); names(d) <- 'data'

ggplot(d) + geom_density(aes(x=data),col=NA, fill='grey30') + opts(panel.background=NULL) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-30, xmax=30, ymin=0, ymax=0.005), fill='white',alpha=0.2)

ggplot(d) + geom_density(aes(x=data),col=NA, fill='grey30') + opts(panel.background=NULL) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-30, xmax=30, ymin=0, ymax=0.005), fill='#FFFFFF40')
```

Comment: Try much lower `alpha`, e.g. 1/256

Comment: @Julius, can you submit that as an answer?  It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yes that's it, thanks @Julius. I must've missed something about the scale as 20% alpha has normally been visible in ggplot and other R.

Comment: @geotheory, I added some more details. I think that you haven't missed anything and that it is somehow related to `geom_rect`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you just have chosen too low `alpha`, try for example `1/256`, which is the lowest possible amount of transparency:

```
ggplot(d) + geom_density(aes(x = data), col = NA, fill = 'grey30') + 
  theme(panel.background = NULL) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -30, xmax = 30, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.005), 
            fill = 'white', alpha = 1/256)
```

[image]

This is an unexpected solution for me too, because taking `alpha = I(1/d)` means that `d` is a number of points that must be overplotted to give a solid colour, so we would expect different result with `1/256`. As you said, that is a quite frequent issue related to `geom_rect`.

Comment: 15 months on and I've finally learned the reason for this! ggplot draws a rect for each row in the data object regardless of whether geom_rect uses it (obvious in retrospect). So a solution is to give geom_rect a single-row data object, e.g. `geom_rect(data=d[1,],..` and problem solved.